# Inverse Density Weighting (IDW) not reaching to edge of mask in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, polygon, inverse-distance-weighted

I am trying to use Inverse Density Weighting to illustrate percent cover of corals on reefs in Hawaii. There is a particular reef (see attached screenshots) where the polygon used for the mask is not completely filled to the edge. For some reason, the interpolation at this specific portion of the reef does not extend all the way to the edge as it should despite survey points lying right next to the edge (see blue waypoints on second photo for reference). This issue is more drastically visible on the left side of the reef where the far left portion of the interpolation is also cut off (see first image of entire reef).

[image]

To do the interpolation, I imported the spatial data (containing waypoints with their associated coral data) into Arcmap (10.7.1). I used the model builder to create an IDW using “coral” as the z value field and M12 as the polygon for the mask. I then reclassified the interpolation into four cover categories or bins to get this projection. I’ve tried manually changing the radius of the mask used to perform the IDW analysis but these odd gaps between the mask edge and interpolation still are present as shown above

[image]
[image]

I’ve made larger polygons and used them as the mask and these gaps still exist. As you can see in the photos above, using a larger mask shows the cut offs seem to come from something unrelated to the data or IDW themselves.
Since the cut-offs are straight lines, that aren’t really correlated to my data points, it seems like it is somehow connected to some other mask or some other underlying factors that this map pack has, that I can’t see. Is this possible and how would I know?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lbOuU2-NLWvXGvhDaHc5atXO3sHlyDx6/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yjsxWNtav6VuyQH9q9hWZK4u46F44Yjh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share your points and polygon mask data?

Comment: There are different ways to set environmental settings.  Maybe you set a processing extent in your project, in the model, or in a tool and that limited your analysis.  See here:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I added the files to the post. @GBG I changed the environment extent and it did make it extend out further but the problem is, it extended out to the furthest points of the mask on each side so that now it is a rectangle. Is there a way for it to extend only to the mask?

Comment: You are doing an interpolation and not an extrapolation.  The output will always be bound by the extent of your data points.